# Can employer change your resignation date on their own even on given written resignation?

Tags: united-states, resignation, india, tech-industry, payroll

I recently resigned from my company for which I have worked 15 days and dropped written resignation email stating that I am quitting job on immediate basis. However I logged in next day by mistake. Now the company has changed my resignation date to the last logged in date and gave me the salary for notice period too(which I didn't served). What should I do now as they are showing my last day as 15+7 = 22 days and it will be a trouble for me as I have joined another company on 16th day.

Comment: Are you in India or US? You tagged two location tags

Comment: The company is US MNC but payroll is of its private indian subsidiary

Comment: So you are actually located in India? Thus why this situation is a problem because of relieving letter, simultaneous jobs etc right?

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do now as they are showing my last day as 15+7 = 22 days and it will be a trouble for me as I have joined another company on 16th day.

You should contact your former company and ask them to amend the date (HR or your former manager would be ok).

You may also want to bring to their attention the extra payment you received, so they can explain their reasons for giving it or so they can correct that payment as well.

Comment: Well they are ready to settle down on payment part but they are saying that as you logged in a day after resignation so it can't be reversed and they will have to show it as last working day even though the login session was for a min only

Comment: HR is ready to document 15th as resignation date but they will give me relieving of 16th only

Comment: Which means my date of exit will be 16 I. E. I worked till 16th which is incorrect

Comment: @MannatGill can't you ask them to include in their document _how long_ did you work that day? e.g. "Mannat Gill last day working for our corporation was on [day 16]. in which he worked for 2 minutes 21 seconds" If they so stubbornly claim they have to detail the last day, then they should detail that as well (note the same could have happened if you finished working 5 minutes after midnight). So they get to document your last day as the 16, but it's clear for anyone reading it that it was not the actual end date.

Comment: @MannatGill, Do what Angel suggested, but make your request via email. This way, if they say 'no' for whatever stupid reason, then you can just staple a paper copy of the email thread to your relieving letter.

Comment: @Angel: I suggested the same thing but they are saying it's non-compliant. ☹️